# How to output multiple less files into one css file which has dependency on variables and mixins in a separate less file

Tags: html, css, less

I have multiple less files where the structure is as follows

```
         LESS 
          variables.less
          mixins.less
          main.less
          grid.less
          button.less
```

variables.less has some variables  such as

```
        @padding-small: 20px;
        @background-color: #fff;
```

Currently each of the less files compiles to its own css file. However i    want all the less files to be compiled to main.css

I tried doing an @import "grid"
                 @import "button"  within main.less but it fails saying some variables defined in variables.less is not found while compiling styles in grid.less

My grid.less looks like this,

```
               @import variables.less
               @import mixins.less

               .grid {
                   padding-top: @padding-small;
                }
```

My main.less also has dependency on variables and mixin.less where i have teh imports specifed this way,

```
             @import variables
             @import mixins
             @import grid
             @import  button
            .body {
               padding-left: @padding-small;
             }
```

But this fails
           I tried,
                   @import (reference) "variables" 
in both grid and button.less,    but compilation fails.
 How could i compile  grid and button.less and other less files into main.css without bothering about the variables or mixins imports for each of teh less files?

Comment: less: {
         development: {
            options: {
               compress: true,
               yuicompress: true,
               optimization: 2
            },
            files: [{
               expand: true,
               cwd: 'src/less',
               src: ['*.less'],
               dest: '<%= config.app %>/css/',
               ext: '.css'
            }]
         }
      }   My gruntfile for less looks like this

Comment: In short, to get `main.css` this way you should compile `main.less` *only* and *do not* compile other of these less files.

Answer (score 0):

`@import variables.less` should do the trick. Because of Less uses [lazy loading](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-lazy-loading) it does not matter where you import the `variables.less`.

Namespaces can be an issue, from http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-namespaces-and-accessors:

> Note that variables declared within a namespace will be scoped to that
>   namespace only and will not be available outside of the scope via the
>   same syntax that you would use to reference a mixin (#Namespace >
>   .mixin-name). So, for example, you can't do the following: (#Namespace
>   > @this-will-not-work).